# How c-array would be stored/represented in memory

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
char buffer[]="foobar";
```

I know that buffer is char* pointer to the first element so buffer==&buffer[0] but 
why &buffer==buffer? &buffer should give the memory address of the buffer char* 
and NOT the address of the first element?

Additionaly,What would happen when i do (int)buffer ?

Comment: The memory address of the buffer *is* the Memory address of the first element.  However `&buffer` and `buffer` do in fact have different datatypes, so you should at least get a warning if you actually code up the Expression `&buffer == buffer`.  Try it.

Comment: If you try `(int)buffer`, the compiler will first turn `buffer` into a pointer and then intepret the bits of that pointer as and `int`.  This might also result in a warning if the pointer is bigger than the int, but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you sure that `&buffer==buffer`? up, please read the OP question again ;)

Comment: `buffer` is *not* a pointer (`char *`) - it's an array (`char []`) - try doing `buffer++` if you want to see one important difference. It will decay to a pointer is various cases though.

Comment: I suggest you read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Please don't make radical changes to your question text ... it confuses people who first view this after the changes are made.

Comment: Please avoid deleting your question after it was answered. SO is meant to be an archive of questions with answers. Just the answers would be rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

buffer is the address of the first element and &buffer is indeed the address of the array itself. The array will be stored on the stack directly. That is why &buffer == buffer.

It is not a pointer but an array. If you had declared it as char*, it would not be &buffer == buffer

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this.

`buffer` is the address of the first element of the array. So it is the address of an integer.

`&buffer` is the address of the array. Hence `&buffer` will be in fact the same as `buffer`, but their behaviour will be different.

For e.g. if you do `buffer+1`, it will increment by the size of int, but `&buffer+1` will increment by the size of the array, i.e size of one element * number of elements.

---

Edits. Initially I had written `buffer++` instead of `buffer+1`. See comments section for the reason I edited it.

Comment: @undur_gongor I don't think Paul said anything about `not doing buffer++`. He said that it is an array, that decays to pointer. Hence, IMO, buffer++ is totally valid.

Comment: @undur_gongor My Bad. Thanks for bringing it to the notice. Just edited my answer.

Comment: Removed downvote (I suggest deletion of the history stuff and all the related comments).

Comment: Could you please improve your answer a little bit further? In C, a pointer **is** not just an address, it also carries the type information. The two addresses are the same, the types not. So the pointers are different.